# Oracle 9i - Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Windows 2003. Pipelined function

Tags: oracle9i, pipelined-function

Thank you for reading and willingness to help me. 
Am basically a java developer and less knowledge on oracle analytics side.

There exists a materialized view that generates daily holdings of customer units which as days goes by slowed down a lot and certain days failed. When analysed, I found it could be better and easy way re-written.

My environment in windows 2003 running inside Hyper-V which allotted 3000 MB.
Oracle Version :

> Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
>   PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
>   "CORE   9.2.0.1.0   Production"
>   TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production
>   NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

Problem statement: Am working on previously written Materialized view that ran every day night. As years goes by found it fails often and taken long time. So searching for ways to simplify as based on date range just creating rows for in between rows could help and its our requirement. Don't want to use all_objects as felt it could scan for each test_hold rows 30410 rows... "select count(*) from all_objects = 30410".

**Following are our steps**.
1:

```
create table test_hold(act_id varchar2(15), fm varchar2(10),
fund varchar2(10),start_dt date,end_date date,holding number(15,4));
```

**2.**

```
select * from test_hold;

ACT_ID  FM  FUND    START_DATE  END_DATE    UNITS   HOLDINGS
A0001   FM1 ABER001 10/03/2004  11/10/2015  100    100
A0001   FM1 ABER001 12/10/2015  20/10/2015  -100        0
A0002   FM2 FSTA001 14/05/2012  03/03/2013  250    250
A0002   FM2 FSTA001 04/03/2013  19/03/2014  300    550
A0002   FM2 FSTA001 20/03/2014  19/10/2015  -550        0
```

**3. Expected output.**

```
ACT_ID  FM  FUND    TRAN_DATE   HOLDNG
A0001   FM1 ABER001 10/03/2004  100
A0001   FM1 ABER001 11/03/2004  100
A0001   FM1 ABER001 12/03/2004  100
A0001   FM1 ABER001 …   
A0001   FM1 ABER001 …   
A0001   FM1 ABER001 11/10/2015  100
A0001   FM1 ABER001 12/10/2015  0
A0002   FM2 FSTA001 14/05/2012  250
```

I Tried Level - 1 ...Connect By and pipelined function.
Found Level - 1 not suited for me. Felt Pipeline suited but when full customer set generated ended up with error like below. Also noticed when I try to create as a table with AS SELECT * from piped function, the oracle.exe memory shown at windows task manager keep on growing from 200000 k to > 1000000 k and never cleared unless restarted oracle service.

```
SQL>set timing on;
SQL> set autotrace traceonly statistics;
SQL> /
ERROR:
`
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kohdtf048], [], [], [], [], [], [],
[]



17536980 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:17:34.06

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         20  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
      64632  consistent gets
       2295  physical reads
          0  redo size
  389043748  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
   12860951  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
    1169134  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
   17536980  rows processed
```

Kindly help whether am proceeding correctly or any other simple alternative ways available. Thank you for your help.